# Universal Covers with one end

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I asked a similar (but different) question on math overflow question here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419362/is-mathbbcp3-minus-two-points-a-universal-covering which got a nice answer. I have a natural follow up question which I will ask first here to avoid spamming.

Suppose that $M$ is a non-compact manifold with one end which is the universal cover of some compact manifold $N$.

Is $M$ neccesarily homeomorphic to the total space of some vector bundle?

Update: There is a counter example. See Danny Rubermans answer here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419782/universal-cover-with-one-end.